# Get Facebook uid from ACAccountStore in iOS?

Tags: iphone, xcode, facebook, ios6, social-framework

Hi i want to get the Facebook user's UID from **ACAccountStore** in iOS 6

```
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];

    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSString *key = @"01234567890123";
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];


        [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
         ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
             if (granted) {
                 NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];

                 //it will always be the last object with single sign on
                 self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

                 //i Want to get the Facebook UID and log it here

                 NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",self.facebookAccount);

             } else {
                 //Fail gracefully...
              NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);

             }
         }];
```

**self.facebookAccount** has UID, but i am unable to get it...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I wanted to get the UID without using the Facebook API. It can done by using the following method

```
    self.accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc]init];

    ACAccountType *FBaccountType= [self.accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];

    NSString *key = @"01234567890123";
    NSDictionary *dictFB = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:key,ACFacebookAppIdKey,@[@"email"],ACFacebookPermissionsKey, nil];


        [self.accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:FBaccountType options:dictFB completion:
         ^(BOOL granted, NSError *e) {
             if (granted) {
                 NSArray *accounts = [self.accountStore accountsWithAccountType:FBaccountType];

                 //it will always be the last object with single sign on
                 self.facebookAccount = [accounts lastObject];

                 //i  got the Facebook UID and logged it here (ANSWER)

                  NSLog(@"facebook account =%@",[self.facebookAccount valueForKeyPath:@"properties.uid"]);

             } else {
                 //Fail gracefully...
              NSLog(@"error getting permission %@",e);

             }
         }];
```

Comment: Please note that the UID found in `properties.uid` can be different than the one returned in the /me graph call.

Comment: @chrysb I know this is an old thread but can you elaborate on why this is? Is it mentioned in the Apple docs somewhere?

Comment: It's a Facebook thing. They're moving towards app-specific user ids, which will be different than your canonical user id.

Answer (score 5):

You need to call the [Facebook Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/); use the SLRequest as follows:

```
NSUrl requestURL = NSUrl.FromString("https://graph.facebook.com/me"); 
SLRequest sl = SLRequest.Create(SLServiceKind.Facebook, SLRequestMethod.Get, requestURL, null);

sl.Account = // your ACAccount object here

sl.PerformRequest((data, response, error) => {
    if (error == null) {
        // success! parse response
    }
    else {
        // handle failure
    }
});
```

That should do it!

Comment: hey thanks for the answer but i would like to get it without calling the Facebook Graph API.